# For Loop Not Stopping

Tags: c++, for-loop, compiler-errors

I have a for loop in a function that won't stop.
Here is the entire function which is used for finding a person's grades, adding them together, then displaying the average onscreen:

```
float Student::average() { 
   cout << "How many grades would you like to enter? (Up to ten)\n";
   float x;
   cin >> x;

   cout << "What is your first grade?";
   cin >> grade[0];
   int i = 1;
   for (i; i = x; i++) {
      cout << "What is the next number?\n";
      cin >> grade[i];
   }
   averageGrade = std::accumulate(grade, grade+10, 0.0);
   averageGrade = averageGrade / 10;

   return averageGrade;
}
```

And here is the for loop on its own:

```
for (i; i = x; i++) {
   cout << "What is the next number?\n";
   cin >> grade[i];
}
```

An error also outputs (but still allows the program to run) saying:

> 1>c:\users\hastudent\documents\visual studio     2008\projects\weapons\weapons\weapon.cpp(25) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'float' to 'int', possible loss of data
>
> 1>c:\users\hastudent\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\weapons\weapons\weapon.cpp(30) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data

The program gets up to the point where it ask for the next number. Then you input the number and it keeps asking you that forever.

Comment: BTW those are _warnings_, not _errors_.

Comment: You should be using an `int` for `x`; I don't think it's possible to enter half of a grade. Also, you should seriously consider using more descriptive names for your variables. Using `i` for the counter is fine, but replacing `x` with `numGrades` will make the code much easier to read.

Comment: I had numGrades before actually, but I changed it for my ease of use. Also, the for loop works now, but now whenever it displays averageGrade, the console just displays its memory address.

Comment: @ChrisMP: we can't correct the display code because you haven't shown it to us.  That's common when you display an array though.  Are you sure you're printing a single variable?

Comment: @MooingDuck all do is a simple    cout << s.averageGrade;
Every thing else is in the function.

Comment: @ChrisMP: ah, `s.averageGrade` is a pointer to the _function_.  You want to call the function and display the result: `s.averageGrade()`.  Calling a function requires parenthesis.

Comment: @MooingDuck No. The function is average(). averageGrade is a member of the class Student. BTW I am calling s.averageGrade in int main.

Comment: @ChrisMP: What is the type of `Student::averageGrade`?  Can you show us that declaration?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4042/discussion-between-mooing-duck-and-chrismp)

Comment: @MooingDuck I have moved this over to a 2way discussion chat.

Answer (score 8):

The `for` loop should read:

```
for (int i = 1; i < x; i++)
```

What you have now (`i = x`) is the *assignment* of `x` to `i`, whereas you probably intended a *comparison*. In this case, the correct comparison to use is "less-than" (`i < x`).

Comment: +1: The middle clause is "for as long as this is the case", not "until this is the case" ... and even if it were, the OP meant `==` not `=`.

Comment: My indices does start from zero. Look at the code before the for loop starts.

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop ran forever because:

- i = x is an assignment, rather than an equality test.
- its value is the value of the left-hand-side
- you gave it non-zero values
- and a non-zero value is true in C++.

If you want an equality test, use ==. However, in this case, you want a < thest.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried printing the value of i in the for loop? You start at x, and keep incrementing.

That should probably be:

```
for(int i=0; i<x; i++) { /* do something */ }
```

Usually you start counting from 0, not 1.

The main issue is that where you do i=x you want to put instead the condition that must hold at each iteration of the loop (that is called the [**loop invariant**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant)), that is i < x if you start with i=0, or i==x as others have suggested, if you start counting from i=1.

Answer (score 1):

The second part of the `for` loop is the "When to continue" condition, not "when to stop".

Since you start with index 1 (unconventional but not unheard of in C++) you should iterate up to the number in question:

`for(i = 1; i <= x; ++i)`

Note that even if the condition were "when to quit" `=` is assignment in C++ while `==` is equality comparison.

Answer (score 0):

use !=(comparison operator) instead of = (assignment operator) in FOR loop.